# stop execution of a bashscript when parent python script is killed

Tags: python, bash

I am running a bash script from a python code. It is working fine but it keeps running even after python script ends. How can I stop bash script when I kill python process.

```
command = SCRIPT + " R > " + OUT_FILE + " 2>/dev/null &"
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)

while(True):
    if OUT_FILE is  modified
        do something on OUT_FILE
```

I can remove & symbol but then, it looks like it is becoming a blocking call. I want it to run in background and after some processing in each iteration in python script, i want to check if OUT_FILE is changed (modified time). if changed, then take some action and if it is not changed, continue with some other calculations.

Comment: Remove the `&` from the end of the command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `&` from the end of the command:

```
command = SCRIPT + " R > " + OUT_FILE + " 2>/dev/null &"
#                                                     ^
```

Also note that the command is safer written in an list like so, this will quote all the inputs:

```
command = [SCRIPT, "R", ">", OUT_FILE, "2>", "/dev/null"];
```

Comment: But then, it looks like it is becoming a blocking call. I want it to run in background and after some processing in each iteration in python script, i want to check if OUT_FILE is changed (modified time). if changed, then take some action and if it is not changed continue with some other calculations

Comment: This works in this case but i was actually looking for popen. Found that later. Thank you.